# Database half filled with nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have a `Product` model. The products belongs to one of the two categories : perishable or non-perishable.

A perishable product has the following specifications :

- datetime : Creation date
- datetime : Expiration date
- integer : Weight

A non-perishable product has the following specifications :

- datetime : Creation date
- string : Brand
- integer : Shape

First I thought to do that :

```rb
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.boolean :perishable
      t.datetime :creation_date
      t.datetime :expiration_date
      t.integer :weight
      t.string :brand
      t.integer :shape

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

But if I do that, my database will be half filled with nil. Is this a problem ? Should I do this another way ?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect opportunity to use subclasses. Perishable and non-perishable items would be two different classes extending from Products.

Comment: But it doesn't change the fact the database will be filled with nil ?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the database would be filled with nil because weight/shape would be nil for perishable or non-perishable right? If that's the case, then you should put weight/shape on the subclasses, and therefore they would never be nil.

Comment: @musicnerd47 You are incorrect, STI still will nil those columns in the DB

Comment: That's what I thought too... So the only way to remain is to use polymorphic associations...

Answer (score 0):

If you foresee the different product types increasingly having more unique attributes than I recommend moving to a polymorphic type, if the product attributes are pretty much won't change much than you can keep this approach and optionally move to an STI model approach, the db columns remain the same but the code will have better separation.

Comment: Saying I want to add other categories, with other specifications, should I use polymorphic type ?

Comment: if each product category requires different set of attributes, than yes. There is a way to do this with STI and storing the each unique set of attributes in a hash but that can be messy. Polymorphism is cleaner.